# TinyMCE add div around in the body from the iframe

Tags: html, iframe, tinymce

I use the TinyMCE. The textarea create the tiny-editor. And the tiny-code create the iframe and in this iframe is the editor. So is it normal!

But now I want a div around the editor, in the body of the iframe. Is there an option to solve my problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLPrn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make something

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#mytextarea",
  tinymce options: ... ,

  toolbar: "add_div",

  setup: function(editor) {

    editor.ui.registry.addButton("add_div", {
    text: "Add Div",
    icon: "plus", // look editor-icon-identifiers page
      onAction: function() {
        var element = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select("#tinymce");
        var content = element[0].innerHTML;
        element[0].innerHTML = "<div>"+content+"</div>";
      }
    }); // close registry.addButton

  }, // close setup function

}); // close tinymce.init
```

Comment: Thanks.. but i want to click a button! The div should be around the body ... not in the Tiny. The div-code should be not save, if i save the content. the div around sholud be only for layout-reasons during edit.

Comment: I solved it this way: I added my own iframe with custom div, which I placed under tiny iframe and made tiny iframe body transparent. Added listeners to tiny iframe that tracked size changes and changed the size of my own iframe.