# How to create div tag inside div dynamically tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, sapui5

i want

```
<div> <div> </div> </div>
```

i want to place the inner div dynamically in rich text editor

[image]

But it storing

Hello All                                   29/6/2020

any help.

thanks in advance

Comment: I am confused by your question.  What do you mean by "rich text editor"? What do you mean by "dynamically"? Do you have an example that you can give us?

Comment: it is storing every thing in p tag only. i want to store in div tag.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62542927/13570513

You can use this like ' innerHTML = "< div>< div>"+content+"< /div>< /div>" '

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put each in a separate div. In the example below I used `position: absolute;` to align the divs where I wanted them. If you want to use `float` then you need to set the width of each element.

```css
.float-left {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 20px;
}

.float-right {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="float-left">Hello All</div>
<div class="float-right">29/6/2020</div>
</div>
```